# How do I override/extend UICollectionView.ScrollPosition?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

Basically I want my `uicollectionview` to be able to scroll to where the users finger currently is. This process would begin with a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` just to be clear, this mean it wouldn't start on the collectionview. The Issue I'm having is the fact I can't really find out how I would make the position the collection view scroll to where the users finger would be. This is why I can't use the `top` `bottom` etc enum cases in  `UICollectionView.ScrollPosition`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible

Comment: @mag_zbc this method doesn't seem to do anything if the content is already on the screen. Trying it now even when the rect isn't on the screen it also does no scrolling behaviour

Comment: *"scroll to where the users finger currently is"* ... can you explain that a little better? Do you have a horizontal scrolling collection view covering part of the screen, and you want to scroll it based on the user dragging a touch somewhere not on the collection view?

Comment: My collection view is vertical scrolling. And I want to scroll it based on somewhere that is not on the collection view, in this case that somewhere would be from a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer `